# Application Client EJB Eclipse Glassfish

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, ejb-3.0, containers, application-client

I'm using *GlassFish Tools Bundle for Eclipse*.

I need to create a bean and a client that tests it. The bean (and its interface) are the following.

```
package mykPK;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.ejb.*;

@Stateless
public class ConverterBean implements Converter {
    private BigDecimal yenRate = new BigDecimal("115.3100");

    private BigDecimal euroRate = new BigDecimal("0.0071");

    public BigDecimal dollarToYen(BigDecimal dollars) {
        BigDecimal result = dollars.multiply(yenRate);
        return result.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
    }
    public BigDecimal yenToEuro(BigDecimal yen) {
        BigDecimal result = yen.multiply(euroRate);
        return result.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
    }
}
```

The interface:

```
package mykPK;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface Converter {
    public BigDecimal dollarToYen(BigDecimal dollars);
    public BigDecimal yenToEuro(BigDecimal yen);
}
```

I create them correctly in an EJB project and run them "as a server". All seems to start correctly.

Now I want to create a client.
I tried to put the client inside the same project, creating a different project ("Application Client Project") or even creating a more general "E application project" with two subproject. The result is the same.

Now, the client code is the following

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import mykPK.Converter; /*of course to to that, i reference in the client project the 
EJB project*/

public class ConverterClient {
    @EJB private static Converter converter;

    public ConverterClient(String[] args) {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConverterClient client = new ConverterClient(args);
        client.doConversion();
    }
    public void doConversion() {
        try {
            BigDecimal param = new BigDecimal("100.00");
            BigDecimal yenAmount = converter.dollarToYen(param);
            System.out.println("$" + param + " is " + yenAmount
                    + " Yen.");
            BigDecimal euroAmount = converter.yenToEuro(yenAmount);
            System.out.println(yenAmount + " Yen is " + euroAmount
                    + " Euro.");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Caught an unexpected exception!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this file, i always get the same:

```
Caught an unexpected exception!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ConverterClient.doConversion(ConverterClient.java:17)
    at ConverterClient.main(ConverterClient.java:12)
```

I suppose this is beacause my client is not in the same *container* of the bean, and it is not "deployed" (I simply run the file). But when I tried the more general "Enterprise Application Project" the results were the same)

So, where to put the client and give him the access (with `@EJB`) to the Bean??

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to inject into a non-managed object. You need to grab the initial context and look it up.

Pretty much the same thing as here:
[cannot find my bean using the InitialContext.lookup() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298364/cannot-find-my-bean-using-the-initialcontext-lookup-method/4305487#4305487)

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace suggests that you've directly launched the main method.  In order to use injection in the main class, you must use the [application client container](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4336/beaku?a=view).

Answer (score 0):

A good example of this working can be [found here](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/examples/Sless.html)  Packaging your client for use with glassfish's application client container (via the "appclient" command) is shown, as is packaging it as a standalone Java app.