# How do I set the JNDI properties for a local EJB bean

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb, jndi

I am trying to learn a bit of Java EE using Maven, JPA and EJB. I am now trying to do a basic EJB lookup by using InitialContext just to get a little bit acquainted with ejb's and stuff. I am extremely new to this and I can't even do the tutorials available on the net because noting makes sense for me. I have spent about 4 hours now reading up on EJB, JNDI and InitialContext but noting I read tells me what I need to know.

I am trying to lookup a local ejb that does a basic read operation from a JPA entity. I have tried the "java:comp/env/beanName" JNDI name but it still does not work. I tried the solution found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298364/cannot-find-my-bean-using-the-initialcontext-lookup-method) post but it also does not work. This is what I did.

I have a simple ejb interface

```
package ejb;

import javax.ejb.Local;
import entity.Person;

@Local
public interface PersonService {
    public Person getPersonByID(int id);
}
```

that is implemented by an ejb

```
package ejb;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.*;
import entity.*;

@Stateless(mappedName="PersonServiceBean")
public class PersonServiceBean implements PersonService {
    //Pass persistence unit to entity manager
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "reporting")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public Person getPersonByID(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(Person.class, id);
    }
}
```

And the above ejb reads from this entity

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


/**
* The persistent class for the person database table.
* 
*/
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Person.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Person p")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int personID;

    private String emails;

    private String firstNames;

    private int organizationID;

    private int researchCategoryID;

    private int researchGroupID;

    private String surname;

    public Person() {
    }

    public int getPersonID() {
        return this.personID;
    }

    public void setPersonID(int personID) {
        this.personID = personID;
    }

    public String getEmails() {
        return this.emails;
    }

    public void setEmails(String emails) {
        this.emails = emails;
    }

    public String getFirstNames() {
        return this.firstNames;
    }

    public void setFirstNames(String firstNames) {
        this.firstNames = firstNames;
    }

    public int getOrganizationID() {
        return this.organizationID;
    }

    public void setOrganizationID(int organizationID) {
        this.organizationID = organizationID;
    }

    public int getResearchCategoryID() {
        return this.researchCategoryID;
    }

    public void setResearchCategoryID(int researchCategoryID) {
        this.researchCategoryID = researchCategoryID;
    }

    public int getResearchGroupID() {
        return this.researchGroupID;
    }

    public void setResearchGroupID(int researchGroupID) {
        this.researchGroupID = researchGroupID;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return this.surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

}
```

The JPA etity is connected to a mysql database and this is the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="reporting" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>entity.Person</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/people"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have a Main class that acts as the client

```
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import ejb.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        PersonService service = (PersonService)ic.lookup("PersonServiceBean");
        entity.Person p = service.getPersonByID(1);
        System.out.println(p.getFirstNames());
    }
}
```

I am using EclipseLink amd Im not sure which application server I'm using, if I am using one at all. Am am using Eclipse if it will help as well. If I try to run the application I get javax.naming.NoInitialContextException exception

`Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:18)`

How else then can I accessthe EJB from Main?

Comment: I guess you got some fundamental concepts wrong. The `main()` method executes a Java SE application, not a Java EE application. Are you trying to use JPA/EJB in a Java SE application? JPA is possible, but EJB can only run in a Java EE container and a Java SE application would only be able to access remote EJBs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run EJBs without an EJB container (provided by an application server like JBoss or Websphere). If you need a good framework to go with JPA why don't you use Spring (I use it both in web application and java batches)? It's as easy to set up and offer every advantage you can get from EJBs.

Comment: Ok thanx, ill do some more research and see if I can figure this out

Answer (score 0):

```
JavaBeans that are running within the container pass their credentials within the InitialContext, which is created to look up the remote EJBs. 

To pass JNDI properties within the Hashtable environment, set them as shown below: 
Hashtable env = new Hashtable(); 
env.put("java.naming.provider.url", "ormi://localhost/ejbexample"); 
env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", 
      "com.evermind.server.ApplicationClientInitialContextFactory"); 
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "guest"); 
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "welcome"); 
Context ic = new InitialContext (env); 
Object homeObject = ic.lookup("java:comp/env/employeeBean");

EmployeeHome empHome =
     (EmployeeHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(homeObject,
                                                   EmployeeHome.class);
```